# Vue router removing query params

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm using Nuxt2/Vue2 and i'm struggling to get my query params when generating my site.

I create my urls in the nuxt config by using entrys from Contentful like this:

```
generate: {
  crawler: false,
  async routes() {
    const items = (
      await fetchEntriesByContentType({ contentType: "items" })
    ).map(entry => {
       const routes = {
         route: `/items/item/${entry.fields.slug}`,
         payload: entry,
       }
       return routes;
    });
   return items;
  }
}
```

If I console log to try and debug in the Nuxt config file it will return the url as expected with params e.g. /items/item/101?type=book

But if I then try and access this in my Vue components using this.$route.path, this.$route.fullPath or this.$route.query ect it never returns anything after the '?'. E.g. with the example above it'll always be /items/item/101

Is there something I need to add to my nuxt config to include query params?
I noticed if I click on this.$route to go to the definition it goes to a vue-router file in my node_modules even though I don't have vue-router installed. Is this causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything inside `map` callback, assuming `routes` have to be returned, it should be like:

```
const items = (
    await fetchEntriesByContentType({ contentType: "items" })
).map(entry => {
    const routes = {
        route: `/items/item/${entry.fields.slug}`,
        payload: entry,
    }
    return routes;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this but unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue